# Python equivalent of MATLAB's rethrow()

Tags: python, matlab, try-catch, try-except, rethrow

I'm trying to port a working MATLAB code in Python. I am trying to create the `var` array with size (`rows`, `cols`). If an exception is raised, I catch it and try again to create the `var` array with size (`rows`, `cols`-1). If `cols` gets to zero, then I cannot do anything else, so I [`rethrow`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mexception.rethrow.html) the previously caught exception.

The code snippet is as follows:

```matlab
% rows, cols init
success = false;
while(~success)
    try
        var = zeros(rows, cols);
        success = True;
    catch ME
        warning('process memory','Decreasing cols value because out of memory');
        success = false;
        var = [];
        cols = cols - 1;

        if (cols < 1)
            rethrow(ME);
        end
    end
end
```

The doc of [`rethrow`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mexception.rethrow.html) states:

> Instead of creating the stack from where MATLAB executes the method, [`rethrow`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mexception.rethrow.html) preserves the original exception information and enables you to retrace the source of the original error.

**My question is: What should I write in Python to have the same results with MATLAB's [`rethrow`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mexception.rethrow.html)?**

In Python, I wrote the following. Is that sufficient?

```py
# rows, cols init
success = False
while not success:
    try:
        var = np.zeros([rows, cols])
        success = True
    except MemoryError as e:
        print('Process memory: Decreasing cols value because out of memory')
        success = False
        var = []
        cols -= 1

        if cols < 1:
            raise(e)
```

Comment: code seems OK - as for me you don't need anything more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The corresponding syntax is just `raise`: `raise e` (note: it’s not a function) **adds** a stacktrace entry for itself.  (In Python 2, it *replaced* the previous stacktrace like MATLAB’s ordinary `throw`, but Python 3 extends it.)